# I need to get the data from database and display them in another activity

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I'm new to android programming. I have a database class in which I have Name, Company, Location columns. In the Main Activity I have AutoCompleteTextBox and a Button. For example, If I enter SUGAR in the search box and click the search button, it should navigate to the database and on the next page it should display as Name=Sugar, Company=Annapurna, Location=Panjagutta. I'm done with my DBHelper class and Main Activity. But I'm unable to finish with the Second.java class i.e where I need to display the values from the Database... Can you please help me out. I'm attaching the code.

The DBHelper class is as follows

```
    public class ProductDataBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
static String db_name="MY_DB";
    static String TABLENAME="Ipay_ReFro_Retailer_Tablet_Details";
    SQLiteDatabase sdb;
    public ProductDataBase(Context context) {
    super(context, db_name, null, 100);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    sdb=getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("create table if not exists '"+TABLENAME+"'(Name text,Company text,Location text)");
    }
    public void Insertion(){
    sdb.execSQL("insert or replace into '"+TABLENAME+"'  values ('sugar','annapurna','PANJAGUTTA')");
    sdb.execSQL("insert or replace into '"+TABLENAME+"'  values ('salt','annapurna','ECIL')");
    sdb.execSQL("insert or replace into '"+TABLENAME+"'  values ('milk','heritage','BANJARA HILLS')");
    }
    public ArrayList<String> getItemDetails(String itemName){
    ArrayList<String> itemdetails=new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor c=sdb.rawQuery("select * from '"+TABLENAME+"' where Name='"+itemName+"'", null);
    if(c!=null){
    while(c.moveToNext()){
    String iName=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Name"));
    String iCompany=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Company"));
    String iLoc=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Location"));
    itemdetails.add(iName);
    itemdetails.add(iCompany);
    itemdetails.add(iLoc);
    }
    }
    return itemdetails;
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }



    }
```

The Main Activity is as follows

```
    public class TejaShopActivity extends Activity {String[] items=  {"sugar","salt","milk"};
    ProductDataBase pdb;
    String itemName;

    ArrayList<String> a=new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final AutoCompleteTextView  sp=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
    Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    pdb=new ProductDataBase(this);
    pdb.Insertion();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,     android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,items);
    sp.setAdapter(adapter);
    sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,
    int pos, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //int id=(int) parent.getItemIdAtPosition(pos);
    itemName=parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
    Toast.makeText(TejaShopActivity.this,""+itemName, 10).show();
    a=pdb.getItemDetails(itemName);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    } 
    });
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String iname=a.get(0);
    String icompany=a.get(1);
    String iloc=a.get(2);
    //when you are navigating to Second.class get the values from the bundle
    Intent i=new Intent(TejaShopActivity.this,Second.class);
    i.putExtra(iname, "itemName");
    i.putExtra(icompany, "Company");
    i.putExtra(iloc, "Loc");
    startActivity(i);
    }
    }); 
    }

    /*@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;*/
    }
```

My Second.java is as follows

```
    public class Second extends Activity{
TextView tv1,tv2,tv3;
ProductDataBase pdb;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);

    tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    tv3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    pdb=new ProductDataBase(this);


    Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();

    String x=b.getString("itemName");
    String y=b.getString("Company");
    String z=b.getString("Loc");

    tv1.setText(x);
    tv2.setText(y);
    tv3.setText(z);

}

    }
```

Kindly can anyone of u solve this problem. I'm struck up here. dunno what to do???

Comment: Change parameters:  i.putExtra("itemName", iname);

Comment: I have tried it, but of no use. I'm able to enter 'salt' or any item in the autcompletetextview that are mentioned in the database. The problem is that I after clicking the Button, It is navigating from that page but the output is not being displayed. The output turns to be blank

Answer (score 1):

in TejaShopActivity, your issue is here:

```
i.putExtra(iname, "itemName");
i.putExtra(icompany, "Company");
i.putExtra(iloc, "Loc");
```

your arguments are reversed. Should be:

```
i.putExtra("itemName", iname);
i.putExtra("Company", icompany);
i.putExtra("Loc", iloc);
```

Comment: After changing also, I'm facing the same error. In the Logcat the error is as follows    " E/AndroidRuntime(1601): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0"

Comment: which line throws the exception?